# ReadFromJsonAsync<T>() method does not serialize 2 level nested classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I am using .aspnetcore 6 and the response object is not correctly searialized.

```
public class AvailableColumns
{
    public List<Column> Columns { get;  } = new List<Column>();
}

public class Column
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Value> Values { get; set; } = new List<Value>();
}
public class Value
{       
    public string InternalValue { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

That way the code is read:

// Before this line there are 20 columns in the object T.

```
response.Data = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<T>();
```

// After response.Data has 0 columns

How to fix it?

Comment: Without knowing what's *in* `response.Content`, and what exactly `T` is in this context, this is rather difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: _"Before this line there are 20 columns in the object T"_ - not sure what does this mean. If you refer to data in the incoming json - please post json itself, possibly you got your json structure wrong or there is casing/naming issue.

Comment: T is AvailableColumns class. response.Content has the serialized class AvailableColumns but with an empty Columns list. I run the code from integration tests cant give you json...

Comment: _"I run the code from integration tests cant give you json"_ - just modify the test to read `response.Content` into a string variable and add it's contents to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not sure how is your api like, be sure your api actually returns AvailableColumns model with data.
2. Be sure add the `set` accessor for the `Columns` property.

   ```
    public class AvailableColumns
    {
        public List<Column> Columns { get; set; } = new List<Column>();   //add set accessor here
    }
   ```

Comment: Wow great that was it! Kisses to you and happy weekend :D

Comment: Just asked myself why was the setter not missing using old web api 2 with newtonsoft? using now asp.net core 6 with newtonsoft did not work. I had to add the setter! odd...